# Are elements in a GeoNetwork Feature Catalog dedicated records?

Tags: metadata, geonetwork

I am looking for a data catalog solution which supports metadata on attribute level. What kind of metadata can be managed for GeoNetwork's Feature Catalog elements? Are the elements dedicated, linkable and searchable records? The documentation does not say much about Feature Catalogs. I just found [this](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/eng/users/annexes/standards/iso19110.html) annex page which is titled with "deprecated". Guessing from the screenshot, elements are not records and only have very few standard metadata fields.

Comment: Generally individual elements are not records in GeoNetwork, but all elements in a record are still searchable.

Comment: I would like to confirm that @nmtoken is correct, I installed a GeoNetwork instance and see that Feature catalog elements are searchable. But the result listed and exported is the Feature catalog record without its sub-elements, unfortunately.